# Acer laptop, Intel 2200BG, wireless "disabled by hardware switch" irrespective of switch position

Tags: wireless, drivers, hardware, acer

I have the problem that on my old Acer Travelmate292 the wireless hardware switch has stopped working a couple releases ago. It worked fine in Windows.

BIOS is at the latest version, the switch is indeed in the "on" position, but this is not recognized by Ubuntu.

Earlier it was possible to switch it on in Windows, and reboot to Ubuntu, and it would work, but I have since deleted my Windows installation, so this workaround is not viable anymore.

`rfkill list all` says hard-blocked yes, soft-blocked no, so `rfkill unblock all` (as suggested in other similar questions) does not work.

How can I get a functioning wireless back? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question with the solution I found at least, not least because, while there are many similar questions (and answers) around for the Intel 2200BG chip, none concerned the `acerhk` module and Acer hardware.

The way I solved this is by installing the `acerhk` module. This Hotkeys module also controls the function of the wireless hardware switch. 
This module was removed in a previous release (9.10?) which is probably why the hardware switch stopped working in the first place. Even the source package was removed from the standard repositories [a while back](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=651785). Luckily, I found [a recent version on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/acerhk), including [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cogito-16/+archive/ppa).

1) Install `acerhk-source`:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cogito-16/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install acerhk-source`

2) Like the README.Debian in `usr/share/doc/acerhk-source` says, do

`sudo module-assistant auto-install acerhk`

3) Load the module according to your model in this [rfswitch.SF model matrix](http://rfswitch.sourceforge.net/?page=laptop_matrix). For me, this was

`sudo modprobe acerhk force_series=290 usedritek=1 verbose=1`

`sudo echo 1 > /proc/driver/acerhk/wirelessled`

This will to everything you need. Your wireless hardware switch should work now.

4) To make this change permanent after reboot, you have to do as explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10567343&postcount=8):

Create the config file
`echo 'options acerhk force_series=290 usedritek=1 verbose=1' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acerhk.conf`

Edit `/etc/rc.local`

```
echo 1 > /proc/driver/acerhk/wirelessled
exit0
```

and `/etc/modules` as root an add an entry for the module

```
acerhk
```

When I think this has stumped me for >1 year (I don't use this laptop very often anymore), and I probably wasted 2+ solid days searching for a solution, it was pretty simple in the end. I hope this will help you, too.

NB: You can also get `acerhk` source from [its homepage](http://www.cakey.de/acerhk/), but this didn't compile for me with the current kernel - `make` just sat there and did nothing, probably the reason why it got kicked out of the standard repos.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem on an Asus X550C laptop. The reason seems to be a nasty bug in "network manager". What you must try to do is:

- open Terminal and type: rfkill list
- if you have a hard block "Yes" (and all the physical switches are on) you just hit the bug.
- from top corner, click on wireless icon and then "Disable networking".
- type in Terminal: sudo service network-manager restart
- wait few seconds and then Re-enable Networking from top corner
- put your computer to sleep via hardware switch (could be Fn+F2 or quick press On/Off button). Do NOT restart ! Just put it into sleep (suspend).
- turn on your computer and the wireless should be on now.

Works for me every time. ;)